# Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR; but I am sysadmin

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to modify a stored proc and I am getting this error because the proc has this line of code:

```
RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
           @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
           @ErrorState -- State.
           ) with log;
```

> Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command.

But I do have sysadmin permissions. What's missing?

[image: screenshot of permissions dialog]

Comment: Can you test it with following statement: CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_RAISERROR AS
RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'sp_test_RAISERROR') WITH LOG;
RETURN;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't running under sa. Once I disconnected and reconnected. It worked !